# how to expand only one collapse panel in ant-design

Tags: reactjs, antd

I'm using Ant-design collapse as accordian , my requirement is when I load page by default first panel should open, and also when I click on other panel whartever the panel is already open should close and only clicked panel should expand.Can someone please help  me on this.

I'm using Ant-design collapse :

https://ant.design/components/collapse/

Regards,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use 'accordion' and 'defaultActiveKey' properties. Something like:

```
import { Collapse } from 'antd';

const { Panel } = Collapse;

const text = `
  A dog is a type of domesticated animal.
  Known for its loyalty and faithfulness,
  it can be found as a welcome guest in many households across the world.
`;

ReactDOM.render(
  <Collapse accordion defaultActiveKey={['1']}>
    <Panel header="This is panel header 1" key="1">
      <p>{text}</p>
    </Panel>
    <Panel header="This is panel header 2" key="2">
      <p>{text}</p>
    </Panel>
    <Panel header="This is panel header 3" key="3">
      <p>{text}</p>
    </Panel>
  </Collapse>,
  mountNode,
);
```

Comment: great ans! just one thins, if he wanted his first panel to be the default one it should be  `defaultActiveKey={['0']}`, and no need to specify `keys` prop on the `Panel`s

Comment: Depends on the keys of the accordion items. In the following sample the keys are beginning from 1.

Comment: The Live example: https://codesandbox.io/s/wt6g8